# ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property

Tags: angular, typescript

I have upgraded the angular 4 application to angular 6. I have basically two projects. The parent project is packaged and referenced in the child project. The screen shot below shows parent project folder called @wtw that is referenced in the client project. The @wtw folder is under the node_modules folder.
 The child project was building the parent package fine when it was in Angular  version 4. Ever since the upgrade has been done to 6 it complains of ts files under the wtw folder seems missing from the TypeScript compilation. Do I need to explicitly include the path in the tsConfig file.

I tried to add the following in the tsConfig but no difference

```
"inlcude": [
    "node_modules/@wtw/**/*"
  ]
```

[image]

tsConfig file

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,

  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "type-definition"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "inlcude": [
    "node_modules/@wtw/**/*"
  ]
}
```

angular.json file

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "app": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "irm",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "../wwwroot",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/favicon.png",
              "src/web.config",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "../node_modules/@wtw/platform/assets",
                "output": "./assets"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "../assets",
                "output": "./assets"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "../IRM.ClientSide/node_modules/@wtw/platform/styling/platform.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "../IRM.ClientSide/node_modules/jsoneditor/dist/jsoneditor.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "app:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "test.ts",
            "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**/*",
              "**/src/app/api/**/*",
              "**/src/polyfills.ts",
              "**/node_modules/**/*",
              "**/src/app/api/**/*",
              "**/src/polyfills.ts",
              "**/node_modules/**/*",
              "**/src/app/api/**/*",
              "**/src/polyfills.ts"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "pdf": {
      "root": "src",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "irm",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "../pdf",
            "index": "pdf.html",
            "main": "pdf.ts",
            "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "assets",
              "favicon.ico",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "../node_modules/@wtw/platform/assets",
                "output": "./assets"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "app:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "test.ts",
            "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**/*",
              "**/src/app/api/**/*",
              "**/src/polyfills.ts",
              "**/node_modules/**/*",
              "**/src/app/api/**/*",
              "**/src/polyfills.ts",
              "**/node_modules/**/*",
              "**/src/app/api/**/*",
              "**/src/polyfills.ts"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "app-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "app:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "app:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "app"
}
```

Comment: In my case, just restart helped!

Comment: Agreeing with the above. The error started when I added a .ts file. Quitting the local client app server and restarting it let it find the new file. I didn't have to edit tsconfig at all.

Comment: Mother of god. I didn't understand your comment @DamianCzapiewski, but indeed a system reboot did solve the problem. : /

Comment: Switching from Powershell to cmd.exe just resolved this for me...

Answer (score 31):

I had same problem, after 2 hour searching i finally found solution. In my case (i'm using Angular), i just set typescript related path into `tsconfig.app.json`(ATTENTION: file name is not `tsconfig.json`). another way is set entire typescript path into `include` section in `tsconfig.app.json` file (see below example).

in `tsconfig.app.json` change:

```
"files": [
    ...,
    "node_modules/jqwidgets-scripts/jqwidgets-ts/angular_jqxbargauge.ts"
  ],
```

or

```
"include": [
    ...,
    "node_modules/jqwidgets-scripts/jqwidgets-ts/**/*.ts"
  ],
```

Comment: moving the project to a shorter path resolved my issue

Comment: Angular + Webpack needs to know where a .ts file lives. If you import that file inside an Angular file (component, service, directive, etc) then it will work. If you try to dynamically import it using import() and you HAVENT import it somewhere else the regular (synchronous) way, then webpack is not gonna be able to find it. So, this is why you need to declare it in the include property inside the tsconfig.app.json

Answer (score 31):

**05-09-2020**

**Angular 10**

My issue was an invalid case of the component path due to copy/paste error :D

Wrong:

```
import { RegisterComponent } from './Register/Register.component';
```

Correct:

```
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
```

Answer (score 19):

In my case had a case mistake while importing the class in another component:

```
import { MyClass } from '../../../shared/models/Myclass';
```

The file was called `MyClass.ts` (capital C) and import from `../../../Myclass` (lower c).

Comment: For me the same: my import statement ended with update-myitem; but my filename actually ended with update-myItem.ts.  The issue was a  lowercase i in my import statement not matching an uppercase I in the associated typescript filename.

Comment: That's weird!
Anything worked perfectly until when I copy-pasted the import from another file, which was (wrongly) uppercased just like lots of others in my project... even restarting the server didn't help, then when I replaced all imports with the right case, it restarted like nothing ever happened.

Answer (score 15):

Appending `"preserveSymlinks": true` may help. It helped when a `working directory` path included a **symlink**.

For example:

```json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "app": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "irm",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "../wwwroot",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "preserveSymlinks": true,
```

Comment: This worked for me. I did the following: symlink a folder from another project into my current project; then changed the INCLUDE section in the `tsconfig.app.json` (Angular 11) and added the "preserveSymlinks": true to the file `angular.json`

Comment: This fixed it for me even when there were no symlinks in the path to the file it said wasn't being compiled.

Answer (score 13):

There are three scenarios that can cause this warning.

In the explanation below I will assume a `src/scripts/example.ts` file which causes the warning.

**Scenario 1)** You include the wrong path. For example `src/scts/example.ts`

**Scenario 2)** You created the file, but you do not include it anywhere inside your project.

**Scenario 3)** You try to import it asynchronously using import() but you do not import it synchronously anywhere inside your project.

Angular + Webpack needs to know where the file is. When you import it synchronously **in at least one of your project files** that are part of an angular app (component, service, directive, pipe, module, etc) then due to that import statement angular will detect and keep in mind that this typescript module exists.

But if you create the .ts file without importing it anywhere, maybe because you want to import it dynamically later at runtime, then you need to include it at the
`tsconfig.app.json`. NOT at `tsconfig.json`, this is important!

Comment: i made the mistake of adding it to tsconfig.json, ur comment helped me figure it out. thnx

Answer (score 7):

You've done it almost correctly, but it needs some corrections:

1. You have a typo in the key `"include"`
2. You need to include directory under `../node_modules`, not bare `node_modules`
3. You also need to include the project directory to `include`, otherwise your code won't be compiled

So the correct way would be:

```
"include": [
    ".",
    "../node_modules/@wtw/**/*"
]
```

Comment: Thanks i added that but now i am getting an error No inputs were found in config file 'tsconfig.json'. Specified 'include' paths were '["../../node_modules/@wtw/**/*"]' and 'exclude' paths were '["**/*.sp
ec.ts","**/*.stub.ts","test/**/*.ts"]'.

Comment: Why do you have `../` twice? And you should also add the project directory to include. I'll update my answer.

Comment: error TS18003: No inputs were found in config file 'tsconfig.json'. Specified 'include' paths were '["../.","../../node_modules/@wtw/**/*"]' and 'exclude' paths were '["
**/*.spec.ts","**/*.stub.ts","test/**/*.ts"]'.

Comment: Are you adding the `include` to the root `tsconfig.json`? Try adding it to `tsconfig.app.json` instead.

Answer (score 6):

I resolved the same problem by adding the `zone-flags.ts` in tsconfig.app.ts file section as shown below

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": true
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts",
    "src/zone-flags.ts", <--- This resolved
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The error log asked me to include 3 ts files shown below:

It worked when I included the following in the tsconfig.app.json

```
"files": [
   ....,
   "src/environments/environment.ts",
   "src/app/app.module.ts",
   "src/app/app.component.ts"
],
```

Answer (score 2):

**I came across this question when i was having the following errors:**

1. `module.ts is missing from the typescript compilation. please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property`

***Solution:***

I fixed the issue by using `Dynamic import` instead. (Though, dynamic import threw another error, please see solution below)

2. `error ts1323: dynamic import is only supported when '--module' flag is 'commonjs' or 'esnext`

***Solution:***

Open these files:  `tsconfig.json`, `tsconfig.app.json` and `tsconfig.tns.json` locate something like `"module": "es2015"` and update to `"module": "esNext"`

This approach work for me and i hope it will do you too

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had error: variables.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation.
Issue was in my import path.

```
import {  
  ClaimService,
} from './shared/data-access/claimDesk/generated';
import { BASE_PATH as CLAIMDESK_BASE_PATH } from './shared/data-access/claimdesk/generated/variables';
```

had to merge it to

```
import {
  BASE_PATH as CLAIMDESK_BASE_PATH,
  ClaimService,
} from './shared/data-access/claimDesk/generated';
```

Answer (score 1):

I solve it in my case by removing mismatch in the filename and the reference to the file in an import statement.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error and discovered that **Angular is case sensitive** about import path

```
import { MyComponent} from '../example/my-component';
```

is different than

```
import { MyComponent } from '../Example/my-component';
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem was a bit different , But I think it is related

I wanted to add a ionic page component page under another one
[Explorer Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FhxP.png)

I faced the same issue . I solved it by adding a line to tsconfig.app.json

```
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts",
    **"src/**/**/*.d.ts"**
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just restart the app/server, that's what worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is generally default setting in most of the project settings, what I observed is angular for some reason do not support direct paths for some files (for example: projects/app/src etc) instead try specifying indirect path (example : ../../src)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar problem too. Posting here to help others in future. It is also something funny at the same time so I believe that it may interest others.

**Background:**

I was migrating from `JS` into `TS` simply by renaming a file extension.

I was already using Webpack and list of output bundles was defined inside its `entry` config field:

```
entry: {
    repository: [
       "./src/repository/newPeople/interviewee.js"
    ],
    components: glob.sync("./src/common/**/*.ts")
}
```

**Problem:**

Before changing the file extension everything works properly.

After changing the extension into `.ts`, everything works fine except this file.

> ./src/repository/newPeople/interviewee.js is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.

I added an entry in `tsconfig.json` just to make sure: `src/repository/**/*.ts` (even if it is redundant because `src/**/*.ts` is already present). It did not help anyway.

**Solution:**

I eventually realized that the file path is actually: `./src/repository/newpeople/interviewee.js`.
Webpack preprocessor (Babel for my case) looks like to be **case-insensitive** when matching input file paths but Typescript compiler in opposition looks like to be **case-sensitive**.

Answer (score 0):

I did a branch change in a git console,  but I work with Visual Studio Code. After that branch change ther error occured. Restarting Visual Studio helped.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I changed the import reference in app.module.ts! It was a conponent inside page folder and I accidentally referenced to Page(capital P)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have a shared folder but most probably Angular default folder naming convention couldn't support it so I rename it by _shared that's it. is toolkit or nay other folder name conflict with the Angular check it...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that I had a typo on my TypeScript file name. For instance, my intention was to name the file as `products.component.ts`, however I have accidentally typed it as `products.component.tss`.

After discovering my mistake, I have renamed the file on VS Code, and I thought that was enough. However, I have kept on getting the error message `ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property`.

I tried to add things to `tscofig.app.json` and so on, but it didn't really work. So I removed them all and put it back to original settings.

It finally did work when I stopped the running server, and retyped the command `ng serve`. After the fresh compilation, everything was fine.

**TL;DR**
1)Your file name might be wrong. Check that.
2)If you changed your file name, but if it still doesn't work, then stop the running server and retype `ng serve`. It might work.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes every import seems to be correctly added and linter shows no errors which was my case. 
I wasted a day trying to figure out what was causing the problem. 
I solved it by importing the file like so

```
import { Something } from 'src/app/path_to_your_file';
```

adding the `scr/app` made it work, and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but you spelt "include" wrong.

```js
"inlcude": [
    "node_modules/@wtw/**/*"
  ]
```

Answer (score -1):

remove zone-flags.ts from  polyfills.ts

Answer (score -1):

The problem I encountered was due to the presence of spaces in the path to the project. I think the root cause is an issue with tsc.

Original:

```
C:\Users\name\folder name\projectfolder
```

Workaround:

```
C:\Users\name\foldername\projectfolder
```

---

It's an issue with the tsc compiler, and it's documented in [this VSCode issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/38408).

Answer (score -2):

All was fine up until I merged a branch to my working branch which was when I got the issue.
Due to a typo, I had generated my component in the wrong folder.
I solved it by moving the component to the right folder and updating all imports...that is after I got hints from some scenarios here .

Answer (score -2):

If you checked and made sure that you don't have a typo, try running `ng update`, and run the application again. It worked in my case. [check this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/17804)

Answer (score -2):

In my case the containing folder was incorrectly capitalised. It was changed to lower case however in file explorer the folder was **still** capitalised. When a new sub folder was added at a later stage the auto generated import path was wrong.

Answer (score -2):

Following @Damian Czapiewski's comment to OP, a **system reboot** (in my case, of Windows) actually solved the problem.

After an hour fighting, this is disconcerting. : /

Answer (score -2):

My issue was case sensitivity in the import statement. Once I noticed that a directory in the import had camel casing, and used the same case in the import, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score -2):

My similar error popped up (ng 10) after I created & completed a new directive in a new branch, then merged it into the main branch. Sometimes after creating a new directive that is used in several components, some of the spec files complain about a missing import/declaration of the new directive. So I added this to each spec file, but was still getting the error. I then 'killed' the terminal that was serving my app (the garbage can icon in VS code terminal), re-started my app using ng serve -o, and presto, no more error.